# Best Time to Buy and Sell Stocks with the constraint of at most two transactions

Tags: algorithm

Question taken up from this website:
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stocks-iii/

Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may complete at most two transactions.

Note:
You may not engage in multiple transactions at the same time (ie, you must sell the stock before you buy again).

**My Solution**:

```
int Solution::maxProfit(const vector<int> &A) {
    int i = 0, sz = A.size();
    int buy_price, sell_price;

    int profit, max_profit1 = 0, max_profit2 = 0;

    while(i<sz){
        while(i<sz-1 && A[i+1] < A[i]) ++i;
        buy_price = A[i];
        while(i<sz-1 && A[i+1] > A[i]) ++i;
        sell_price = A[i];
        profit = sell_price-buy_price;

        if(profit > max_profit2) {
            swap(max_profit1, max_profit2);
            max_profit2 = profit;
        }
        else if(profit > max_profit1) max_profit1 = profit;

        ++i;
    }

    return max_profit1 + max_profit2;
}
```

My idea is to keep a track of all the profits(wherein I buy at local minima and sell at local maxima); and pick up the top two ones. I keep a track of the 2 maximum profits in variables max_profit1 and max_profit2 wherein max_profit1 < max_profit2.

I tried this for various cases and got the desired answer but I'm facing incorrect submission on the OJ. Please help me point out the flaw in the approach - wanted to avoid DP for this case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local Minimums and maximum might not be optimal because we have 2 transactions available.

Your code sometimes uses wrong local minimums/maximums

For example given input:

> 1 1 3 1 3 2 4

Your solution gives: 4

Correct asnwer is: 5

Comment: But according to the problem statement, we can't buy again before selling. In your example, we're buying before selling off. Am I correct?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta Yes you are correct, sorry i misunderstood the question, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Why did you want to avoid dynamic programming?

If we iterate backwards, we know the best sell for each possible buy - it's the max seen so far. We can also record and update as we go the best transaction from where we are to the end.

If we iterate forwards, we know the best buy for each possible sell - it's the min seen so far. We can also record and update the best transaction from where we are to the start. *And* we can update the overall solution by pairing where we are with the transaction we already recorded for the best buy from index `i + 1` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This would fail for the following input:
[1,2,4,2,5,7,2,4,9,0]

In this case, the answer should be 13. (Buy on day 1, sell on day 6 and buy on day 7 and sell on day 9).

But according to the code, it returns 12.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was meant as an actual answer or as a comment or more information that should be in the body of the question.

Comment: I realised this later on that it would fail for this input; which in turn made me realise that my initial approach would fail for the question and why dp should be used.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```cpp
public int maxProfit(int[] prices) {
    int sell1 = 0, sell2 = 0;
    int buy1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE, buy2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        buy1 = Math.max(buy1, -prices[i]);
        sell1 = Math.max(sell1, buy1 + prices[i]);
        buy2 = Math.max(buy2, sell1 - prices[i]);
        sell2 = Math.max(sell2, buy2 + prices[i]);
    }
    return sell2; 
}
```